# Arduino Input pin from external system

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Is possible for Arduino to receive a 5V into a inputPin from a external battery?

If I have a system that has it's own power supply and after an event fires 5V. How can Arduino read this input?

Comment: What in particular is missing from the specification/documentation? Are you wondering about just any of their products?

Comment: I could not find anything related or if this feature exists.

Comment: You may be able to find information from  "http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalReadSerial". The line 'int buttonState = digitalRead(pushButton);' is code to read the status ,High(5V) or Low(0V), of the pin.

Comment: Just to mention: The 5V signal from your external system is relative to the GND of your external system. Input Voltage on your Arduino Pins is relative to the Arduino GND. So you have to connect both GND (external system and Arduino) to be able to read something on the Arduino input pin. Otherwise behaviour is undefined or you might even destroy your Arduino (not sure if there are clamping diodes or some other protection mechanisms on the input pins of the ATMega).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an electrical problem, no software issue I presume.

Here is how to proceed:
1) Make sure both boards have the same ground (connect GND together and make sure there is no conflict)
2) Connect your output to an input on the Arduino board (pin 2 e.g.). This connection is preferably done using a resistor, 1 kOhm will be ok.

On software side, just set this pin as input `pinMode(2,INPUT);` in `setup()` and then get its value `status = digitalRead(2);` in `loop()`.